# Cordova Google Maps Plugin Installation For Phonegap

Tags: google-maps, cordova, plugins, installation, phonegap

I'm trying to install cordova-plugin-googlemaps for phonegap, but it gives me this error:

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-googlemaps': CordovaError: Uh oh!
>   target destination "/Users/imac/Desktop/app/FFG - City
>   Guide/platforms/ios/FFG - City
>   Guide/Resources/pgm_Localizable.strings" already exists

I checked above mentioned folder, but pgm_Localizable.strings not really exists. Please Help Me. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing and re-adding `ios`:

```
$> cordova platform rm ios

$> cordova platform add ios
```